# User last login and user last visit problem

Tags: user-meta

Need some help with debugging. I have two function is functions.php One to capture user last login

```
function user_last_login( $user_login, $user ) {
    update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'last_login', time() );
}
add_action( 'wp_login', 'user_last_login', 10, 2 );
```

and second to capture user last visit (in case if is permanently logged in)

```
function user_last_visit() {

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        update_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'last_visit', time() );
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'user_last_visit', 10 );
```

Then I try to display all the user data showing: nickname, date_of_registered (function in plugin), last login and last visit.

```
$users = get_users();
 foreach( $users as $user ) {

   $udata = get_userdata( $user->ID );             
   $user_registered = $udata->user_registered;             
   $user_last_login = get_user_meta( $user->ID , 'last_login', true );
   $user_last_seen = get_user_meta( $user->ID , 'last_visit', true );

   printf( '%s  OD : %20s : Last Login : %20s : Last seen : %20s <br> ', 
          $udata->data->display_name, 
          date( "M Y", strtotime( $user_registered )), 
          human_time_diff( $user_last_login ),
          human_time_diff( $user_last_seen )                      
         );
 }
```

Everything, except last visit work. What could be the problem with last visit??

Thank you for help.

S.

Comment: what do you mean by not work last visit ? what returns last_visit ?

Comment: 50 years, not the time stamp of last visit.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `human_time_diff` for convert time to human readable format. your `last_visit` meta empty that is why it is return 50 years. so before convert `human_time_diff`  you have to check value is not empty. use below code to display `last_login`, `last_visit`.

```
$users = get_users();
 foreach( $users as $user ) {

   $udata = get_userdata( $user->ID );             
   $user_registered = $udata->user_registered;             
   $user_last_login = get_user_meta( $user->ID , 'last_login', true );
   $user_last_seen = get_user_meta( $user->ID , 'last_visit', true );

   $user_last_login = !empty($user_last_login) ? human_time_diff($user_last_login) : '-';
   $user_last_seen = !empty($user_last_seen) ? human_time_diff($user_last_seen) : '-';

   printf( '%s  OD : %20s : Last Login : %20s : Last seen : %20s <br> ', 
          $udata->data->display_name, 
          date( "M Y", strtotime( $user_registered )), 
           $user_last_login ,
           $user_last_seen                       
         );
 }
```

Comment: thank you.  it works.